# How to Toggle "a" tag elements to show hidden DIVs just like the Facebook notification center

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my source code, I have two `a` elements I want to toggle to display a hidden div with content one at a time. Just like how the Facebook notification center operates when the icons are clicked and I think, all of you have at-least interacted with the Facebook notifications center on the top left near the logo on the Facebook website. How do they workout that?

Here is my code below

```
    <style>
    div, a {
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    a {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;  
        background: #ececec;  
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
        padding: 5px 20px;  
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #one {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .dn_js {
        display: none;
    }

    .db_js {
        display: block;
    }

</style>
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <div id="one">
        <a href="#" data-open="frdz" class="aTggl active">Friends</a>
        <div id="frdz" class="innerWrap dn_js">Mike</div>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <a href="#" data-open="Ntfn" class="aTggl">Noticiations</a>
        <div id="Ntfn" class="innerWrap dn_js">Peter</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery code below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(".aTggl").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);

            $(".active").removeClass("active");

            $this.addClass("active").parent().siblings().children(".innerWrap").addClass("dn_js");

            var content_show = $(this).data("open");
            $("#"+content_show).addClass("db_js"); 
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: But where is your html, maybe a small jsfiddle demo would help.

Comment: I have added my HTML. Sorry, I didn't realize that I hadn't included it at first.

Comment: I've created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RWzuD/ for you, now pls describe the action which you like to happen. Actually on click the hidden div's appear. If you want to get help don't expect the people to visit facebook first to guess what you want. :)

Comment: Why this spaghetti? Why don't you just use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)?

Comment: Thanks for the help @smb and the advise too :). What I want is, when The user clicks on the any of those `a` tag elements, That clicked `a` tag element should be active with it's hidden DIV with the contents shown. Clicking on the same `a` tag element should be able to able to toggle its respective DIV with the contents on and off. 

And in the case of clicking on the other `a` tag element, the other `a` tag should be not be active and its DIV element should be hidden.

Comment: See my answer now it should work properly.

Comment: I have seen it already and it is working. Thanks for your answer and time too. :)

Comment: It would be great if you accept it as answer so others can see fast what is working or not and your issue is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here you are, like mg007 pointed out already better use toggle() and toggleClass()

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dASdJ/2/

```
var switchToggle = function (toggleEle) {
    $('#' + $(toggleEle).data('open')).toggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
          $(this).parent().children('.aTggl').toggleClass('active');
    });
 }

$('.aTggl').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switchToggle($(this));

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.active').each(function() {
          switchToggle($(this));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer @smb. Let me edit my code and get it working.